# A Cantor-type set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A=\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!} : a_k\in\{0,\,1\}\}$.

We can prove that $A$ is a closed set with $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$ and Lebesgue measure of $0$.

Is there a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $A+A+\cdots+A$ ($m$ times) is of positive Lebesgue measure?

(Note that for the Cantor set $C$ we have $C+C=[0,\,2]$.)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A nice question.  If no one else answers, I will provide an answer later (no time now).

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this set is homeomorphic to the ordinary middle thirds Cantor set?

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for your time. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: @LeeMosher No, I don't know this. Actually my first thought was using Steinhaus's Lemma somehow but I got nowhere

Comment: @LeeMosher  The set $A$ is compact, nonempty, nowhere dense, and has no isolated point.  Thus it is homeomorphic to the middle-thirds Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference...

*Erdős, Pál; Volkmann, B.*, [**Additive Gruppen mit vorgegebner Hausdorffscher Dimension**](https://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN243919689_0221) [Additive groups with given Hausdorff dimension], J. Reine Angew. Math. 221, 203-208 (1966). [ZBL0135.10202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0135.10202).

For each $\alpha \in (0,1)$, they define an additive [sigma-compact] subgroup $G(\alpha)$  of $\mathbb R$ with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$.  [For more detail, see below.]  For every $\alpha$, your set $A$ is a subset of $G(\alpha)$.  Since $G(\alpha)$ is a group, $A+A+\dots +A \subseteq  G(\alpha)$.  So $A+A+\dots+A$ has Hausdorff dimension at most $\alpha < 1$, and thus contains no interval.

[Of course, this is true for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$, so $A+A+\dots+A$ has Hausdoff dimension $0$.]

---

More detail from the Erdős & Volkmann paper.  Each real number $x$ has a unique "Cantor expansion" of the form
$$
x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{a_k(x)}{k!}
\tag1 $$
where $a_k(x) \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \le a_k(x) < k$.  Fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$.  Let $G(\alpha)$ be the set of all reals $x$ such that:
there exists $\kappa = \kappa(x) > 0$ and $k_0 \in \mathbb N$ such
that, for all $k \ge k_0$
\begin{align}
\text{either}\qquad & a_k(x) \le \kappa\;k^\alpha
\\ \text{or}\qquad & a_k(x) \ge k - \kappa\;k^\alpha .
\tag 2\end{align}

**Satz 1.** $G(\alpha)$ is an additive group with $\dim G(\alpha) = \alpha$.

The proof that $G(\alpha)$ has dimension $\alpha$ is relatively easy.  The more involved part is the proof that $G(\alpha)$ is a group.  They have to keep track of "carrying" when you add two expansions of the form $(1)$ with restrictions $(2)$.

---

**Plug**

My paper with Miller,

*Edgar, G. A.; Miller, Chris*, [**Borel subrings of the reals**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-02-06653-4), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 131, No. 4, 1121-1129 (2003). [ZBL1043.28003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1043.28003).

We show a Borel set $\subseteq \mathbb R$ which is a subring is either all of $\mathbb R$ or else has Hausdorff dimension zero.  That was a question asked by Volkmann in 1960.

Comment: That looks fantastic! However I lack the knowledge of Hausdorff dimension, so I was seeking for a much simpler solution, I guess. I have proven that every number in [0,e-1] can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty \frac {a_k}{k!}$ where $a_k \in $ ${0, 1, ..., k-1}$ and I was hoping it would help with the solution.